# New nulls when assigning series to dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I can't figure out why new null values are popping up after assigning a dataframe column as a series that doesn't have any nulls originally. Here's an example:

`df.date_col.shape` returns (100000,)
`df.date_col.isnull().sum()` returns 0

I then create a new series of the same size with:
`new_series = pd.Series([int(d[:4]) for d in df.date_col])`
`new_series.shape` returns (100000,)
`new_series.isnull().sum()` returns 0

But then if I try to assign this new series to the original column:
`df.date_col = new_series`
`df.date_col.isnull().sum()` returns 6328

Would someone please tell me what might be going on here?

Comment: Your index is not continue.

Comment: Huh, sorry what's the problem with my indexing?

Comment: You can try to look at my answer, simple fix will be `df.date_col = new_series.values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, your index is not continue , when you create the `pd.Series`, it auto assign the index from 0 to len(s)-1, dataframe assign is base on the index , index miss match will create the `NaN`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3]},index=[1,2,3])


s=pd.Series([d*2 for d in df.col])

df['New']=s

df
Out[170]:
   col  New
1    1  4.0
2    2  6.0
3    3  NaN


df['New2']=s.values
df
Out[172]: 
   col  New  New2
1    1  4.0     2
2    2  6.0     4
3    3  NaN     6
```

Comment: Thanks! will accept this answer as soon as it allows

Comment: @Jake yw~ :-) happy coding